# SCSS change atribute of element based on sibling's child

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there some way how to check if sibling's child has some class and stay in current element?

E.g.:

```
<div>
  <div className="element">
    <div className="child">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="element">
    <div className="child expand">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="element">
    <div className="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If element "child" has class "expand" I wanna change e.g color of all elements "element".

Comment: I believe you're looking for the :has selector

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi It looks like this is what I'm looking for, thanks. However support for this selector is not very widespread in browsers :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to do it with SCSS is with :has(), which as mentioned is not well supported yet. At the time of answering, it's only Firefox, Firefox for Android and Samsung Internet that do not support it (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)).
It would look like this:

```
.element:has(.expand) {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly in SCSS because it's a preprocessor language with no access to the DOM. To accomplish this, you would need to use JavaScript.